# Address Sanitizer - How to set >1 ASAN_OPTIONS?

Tags: windows, address-sanitizer, sanitizer

I'm on Windows using Visual Studio compiler.
I'm using `/fsanitize=address` to compile with AddressSanitizer.
I run my exe from command line.

I want my exe to

1. continue on ASAN errors and
2. write all ASAN errors to a logfile

The [documentation of ASAN_OPTIONS](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerFlags) suggests the following syntax:
`set ASAN_OPTIONS=continue_on_error=1:log_path=log_file my.exe`

However, I only can (partially) succeed, when I
a) omit the exe name AND
b) use only 1 option

When specifying the executable name, I always get the error
`Internal error duing continue on error: Fail on write()`
(no matter
whether I use the full path name or the exe file name only,
or if I'm in the exe's directory or not)

And when using more than 1 option, only 1 option is working.
I tried the delimiter characters   (space) and `:`.
Surrounding the whole option string with quotes (`"`) is counterproductive: then no option is recognized at all.

*Edit* after @yugr's answer: I experimented a little further and experienced the following:

- 2 options:
  `>set ASAN_OPTIONS=log_path='D:\_tmp\log_file':continue_on_error=1`
  continues, but **does not writa** a logfile
- exchanged option order:
  `>set ASAN_OPTIONS=continue_on_error=1:log_path='D:\_tmp\log_file'`
  continues, but **does not writa** a logfile
- logfile only:
  `set ASAN_OPTIONS=log_path='D:\_tmp\log_file'`
  works: **does** writa a logfile
- different delimiter: space
  `>set ASAN_OPTIONS=continue_on_error=1 log_path='D:\_tmp\log_file'`
  continues, but **does not writa** a logfile
- exchanged option order with delimiter space:
  `>set ASAN_OPTIONS=log_path='D:\_tmp\log_file' continue_on_error=1`
  continues, but **does not writa** a logfile
- different delimiter: semicolon
  `>set ASAN_OPTIONS=continue_on_error=1;log_path='D:\_tmp\log_file'`
  `>my.exe`
  **`Internal error duing continue on error: Fail on write()`**

*Edit end*.

---

I tried the option `log_path` with

1. `stderr`
   => AddressSanitizer output occurs on stderr instead of stdout (note: the [doc](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerFlags) states a default value of stderr, which is obviously not the case here)
2. `log_file`
   => works (the file log_file.<pid> occurs in the current directory, not in the exe directory)
3. `D:\_tmp\log_file`
   => gives `AddressSanitizer: ERROR: expected '=' in ASAN_OPTIONS` - don't know why:
   `> echo %ASAN_OPTIONS%`
   `log_path=D:\_tmp\log_file`

---

Any hint is highly appreciated on the 3 dubieties (exe name in options, >1 option, path in `log_path` option).

Comment: Note that `continue_on_error` is a [Windows-specific extension](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/addresssanitizer-continue_on_error/) of Asan. On Linux the closest equivalent is to compile with `-fsanitize-recover=address` and then run with `ASAN_OPTIONS=halt_on_error=0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The documentation of ASAN_OPTIONS suggests the following syntax:
> set ASAN_OPTIONS=continue_on_error=1:log_path=log_file my.exe
> ...
> When specifying the executable name, I always get the error

That syntax is Linux-specific. On Windows you should run it with two separate commands

```
> set ASAN_OPTIONS=log_path=log_file
> my.exe
```

Multiple flags in `ASAN_OPTIONS` can be separated via `:` or   (whitespace):

```
> set ASAN_OPTIONS=verbosity=2:log_path=log_file
> set ASAN_OPTIONS=verbosity=2 log_path=log_file
```

> D:\_tmp\log_file
> => gives AddressSanitizer: ERROR: expected '=' in ASAN_OPTIONS - don't know why:

Yes, this is a (mis)feature of Asan - it treats any unescaped colon as option separator so when you do

```
set ASAN_OPTIONS=log_path=D:\_tmp\log_file
```

it treats "\_tmp\log_file" as second option and fails to parse it. You should escape filename to prevent Asan from doing this:

```
set ASAN_OPTIONS=log_path='D:\_tmp\log_file'
```

> 2 options:
> set ASAN_OPTIONS=log_path='D:_tmp\log_file':continue_on_error=1
> continues, but does not writa a logfile
>
> exchanged option order:
> set ASAN_OPTIONS=continue_on_error=1:log_path='D:_tmp\log_file'
> continues, but does not writa a logfile

This happens because `continue_on_error=1` [forces output to stdout](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/addresssanitizer-continue_on_error/) and overrides the `log_path` setting.

Comment: Thanks @yugr! Your idea about the colon in the path is clear. And I can confirm it. BTW: As directory delimiter between the `'`s work all 3 variants: ``\`` , ``\\``, `/`. - But what about the most important question: How to get more than 1 option working?

Comment: @MattTT I think the issue is caused by `continue_on_error=1` flag - according to [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/addresssanitizer-continue_on_error/) it means "dump to stdout" and seems to override `log_path`. I get expected results with other flags e.g. `set ASAN_OPTIONS=verbosity=2:log_path='D:\_tmp\log_file'`

Comment: Bingo! And [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/sanitizers/asan-continue-on-error) is the MS VS doc for it. Unfortunately, there is no comprehensive list of further VS-specific options. I only found in addition: `detect_stack_use_after_return=1` in the [build & debug reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/sanitizers/asan-building) and `windows_hook_rtl_allocators=true` in [this blog from 2019](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/addresssanitizer-asan-for-windows-with-msvc/).

Comment: When you edit your answer @yugr, I will accept it.

Comment: I use [`COE_LOG_FILE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/sanitizers/asan-continue-on-error?view=msvc-170#select-where-to-send-asan-output) now. Note: `COE_LOG_FILE` is a seperate env var and not part of the `ASAN_OPTIONS` and (unlike `log_path`) does not support a path enclosed in `'` or `"`.

Comment: @MattTT I added info about `continue_on_error=1` to the answer.